# Google Scripts - Combine multiple arrays in vlookup type fashion

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to get an array to print out information from two different sources. I am looking for something that will look up one set of values, print the array. then take a value from the first array, use this in a vlookup type fashion, find the value in the second array, and then create a new array that has all the values I need.

So take this code below. I am grabbing the fields I care about in the 'contents' variable, and printing it to an array oA. But in 'contents2' there is another value that I also care about, which I am currently printing to oA2. Based on what I've done so far I have two different arrays, that I basically need to append together. Since the first array could be 10 items or so, and the list on contents2 could be 100 items, I'm looking for a way to take the value I've seen in oA and use that as a vlookup value in contents2 and print that in a new array.

```
function myfunction5() {

 var contents = '{"pagination":{"ending_before":null,"starting_after":null,"previous_ending_before":null},"data":[{"name":"NMR Wallet","balance":{"amount":"0.00000000","currency":"NMR"},"created_at":"2021-02-14T16:46:46Z"},{"name":"SNX Wallet","balance":{"amount":"0.00000000","currency":"SNX"},"created_at":"2021-02-14T16:46:46Z"},{"name":"UMA Wallet","balance":{"amount":"2.00000000","currency":"UMA"},"created_at":"2021-02-14T16:46:46Z"}]}'

 var contents2 = '{"data":[{"currency":"USD","rates":{"NMR":"3668.31071","UMA":"0.034456619116532285","UNI":"0.033166560810060086"}}]}'

 var obj = JSON.parse(contents);

 var obj2 = JSON.parse(contents2);

  let oA=[];
  obj.data.forEach((o,i)=>{
    if(o.balance.amount>0) {
      oA.push([o.balance.currency,o.balance.amount]);
    }
  });

  let oA2=[];
  obj2.data.forEach((o,i)=>{
      oA2.push([o.rates.UMA]);
  });

Logger.log(oA);
Logger.log(oA2)

}
```

This will produce the following:

```
10:53:38 AM Notice  Execution started
10:53:38 AM Info    [[UMA, 2.00000000]]
10:53:38 AM Info    [[0.034456619116532285]]
10:53:38 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

But I really want it to produce:

```
[[UMA, 2.00000000, 0.034456619116532285]]
```

Any pointers on the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

You can use bracket notation to reference a property using a variable. Note that in the sample code I changed the NMR balance to 1 so it will be displayed as well.

```
function myfunction() {

 var contents = '{"pagination":{"ending_before":null,"starting_after":null,"previous_ending_before":null},"data":[{"name":"NMR Wallet","balance":{"amount":"1.00000000","currency":"NMR"},"created_at":"2021-02-14T16:46:46Z"},{"name":"SNX Wallet","balance":{"amount":"0.00000000","currency":"SNX"},"created_at":"2021-02-14T16:46:46Z"},{"name":"UMA Wallet","balance":{"amount":"2.00000000","currency":"UMA"},"created_at":"2021-02-14T16:46:46Z"}]}'

  var contents2 = '{"data":[{"currency":"USD","rates":{"NMR":"3668.31071","UMA":"0.034456619116532285","UNI":"0.033166560810060086"}}]}'

  var obj = JSON.parse(contents);

  var obj2 = JSON.parse(contents2);

  let oA=[];
  obj.data.forEach((o,i)=>{
    if(o.balance.amount>0) {
      let curr = o.balance.currency;
      oA.push([curr,o.balance.amount]);
      obj2.data.forEach((o,i)=> {
        oA[oA.length-1].push(o.rates[curr]);
      });
    }
  });

console.log(oA);

}
```

### Sample Result:

[image]

### References:

[Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

### Addendum:

If you want to use the new format in your comment, you need to check each `obj2.base` like this:

```
 obj2.data.forEach((o,i)=> {
   if (o.base == curr) {
        oA[oA.length-1].push(o.amount);
   }
 });
```

Comment: This is super helpful, and thank you very much for this!! I realize that I provided the wrong format for contents2. So instead, contents2 is actually `'{"data":[{"base":"NMR","currency":"USD","amount":"3668.310"},{"base":"UMA","currency":"USD","amount":"0.034456"},{"base":"UNI","currency":"USD","amount":"0.033166"}]}` Given that format, how could I then handle line 17 from your sample result to account for that format? If I change line 17 to `oArray[oArray.length-1].push([o.amount]);` then it pushes ever single amount value and not just the value I care about.

Comment: You would have to check each value of ````obj2.base````. Push ````o.amount```` to the array if currencies match.

Comment: Can you provide an example of that? Tried a few variations and can't seem to get it to work properly.

Comment: I added an example in the answer

Comment: Thank you!! Much appreciated your assistance on this one.